# Github api token scope to list issues of a private repo?

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api

I want to list all issues of a private repo. I have created an api key. Without any scope I cannot see the issues. If I add "repo" scope, I see them, but that scope can read/write the whole repo.
**Which is the strictest scope I can use to read issues?**

For reference, here is how I am testing it:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token the_token" "https://api.github.com/repos/organization/repo/issues?state=all&per_page=100"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To grant a personal access token access to any data with a *private* repository (code, issues, projects) you'll need to set the `repo` scope.

Unfortunately there's no granularity for issues beyond the `repo` scope.

Comment: Github has now introduced Fine-grained personal access tokens - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78226880/3313618

Answer (score 0):

GitHub now has Fine-grained personal access tokens, which you can use to set read/write permissions on Issues

[image: Fine-grained personal access tokens on GitHub]

[image: Fine-grained personal access tokens on GitHub]